# Scanner directly to printer

Tags: usb, printing

Is there any way possible to connect a business card scanner to a printer, bypassing a computer? The scanner is set up to scan without being connected to a computer. It has 512 MB built in memory. The scanner has the following specs and system requirements:
Scanner specifications:

Document feeding: Sheet feed type (single) 
Resolution (default): 300dpi 
Document Size (Max): Up to A6/4’’ x 6’’ 
Interfaces: SD, xD, Microsoft, Microsoft Pro, MMC, USB Slave (type-B Mini), USB Host (Type-A) For USB Flash Drive 
Output File format: JPEG 
Flash Memory: 512 MB Flash Memory 
Battery: 700 mAh Lithium ion polymer rechargeable battery through USB cable
Fully charged~ Ultra Battery Low (RED LED blinking & power off anytime)

> 150 +/- 20 pages @ 4x6 * based on defined test conditions
>   Charging Method: USB Cable

Comment: Would like it to be a streamlined process, where you scan the card and a copy prints on the printer.

Comment: @Scott: Please don't add comments to your own question.  It's your question.  Please put **all** the information in the question and delete the comment.

Comment: This question is off-topic here. A moderator will probably move this to another Stack Exchange site like Super Users.

Comment: So you need a copier?

Answer (score 1):

The best chance I see for a "direct connection without PC" is the SD-card slot. I assume that it is possible to scan a business card into an image file on the SD-Card without a PC.

On the printer side there are a lot printers available that have SD-card slots and that are able to print images directly from an SD-card without an attached PC.

An advanced version would be using an SD-Wifi-Card. There are some cards available like the like Eye-Fi card that can be used in cameras (or business card scanners) and that act exactly like a regular SD-card. May be it is possible to get a printer to directly print images that are accessible through such a card. May be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can *connect* them, but unless either the scanner or the printer is smart enough to push/pull documents to/from the other device, there's no way of getting anything *across* the connection.